# Android listview footer doesn't fit properly

Tags: android-layout, android

I have the following layout influenced by accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951407/android-footer-in-a-listview)

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    ....
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            layout="@layout/footer" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/song_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_animation"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_list_row_song" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and footer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_ad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/adv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

which produce this image

[image]

My problem is that I want the footer at the end of layout and fill_width and then maitain height to make the image fill real mobile screen width. I can do this by setting a certain list-height but don't want that to support longer screens.

Is there any way to calculate  footer width first and maintain its height when its at bottom of layout, then assign remaining height to list? and how?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers, I've figured out best way to do this, I scaled my image to be wider than device screen, and I used

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/adv" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/song_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_animation"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_list_row_song" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - In footer xml, you souldn't match parent size, but wrap its contents.
2 - ListView height should match the remaining parent size.

So, it's just a matter of swapping these two height attributes and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#EE4566" >

    <!-- add list view here  -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <!-- add footer here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/song_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_animation"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_list_row_song"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        layout="@layout/list_item" />

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/adv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/img1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"

       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this,may be it will help you.