# android button in a class that extends ListActivity

Tags: android

In a class that extends ListActivity where each item I am creating appears as multiple items. I want to have "only one" button at the bottom of my UI....The problem is, when I create that button it appears as a list of buttons which is not what i want...I only need one button....can anyone help?
Here's my code,

```
public class ListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

TextView label;
CheckBox checkBox;
private ArrayList<Boolean> status = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
  String[] objects) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        status.add(false);
    }
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

 View row = convertView;

 if(row==null){
  LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false); 

 }  


 label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.months);
 label.setText(month[position]);



 checkBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
 checkBox.setFocusable(false);
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

         String event = null;

         if (isChecked) 
         {
         status.set(position, true);
         event = " just checked!";
         } 

        else 
         {
         status.set(position, false);
         event = " just unchecked!";
         }

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checkbox " + position +event,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

 }
 });
 checkBox.setChecked(status.get(position));



 return row;
}
}

String[] month = {
    "January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
  };

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // setContentView(R.layout.main);
 /*setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek));*/


   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.main, month));


   //here are the button I am talking about     
   Button saveButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);




  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one button at the bottom then you can either position the button below your listview, or use a footer view as described here:

[Android ListView Footer View not being placed on the bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093481/android-listview-footer-view-not-being-placed-on-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Comment: how to position in below the listview?
Can you send me the xml for that?

Comment: the problem is that I am not defining any listView in my xml, so how come I position it below the ListView?

Comment: you are adding the listview to some container correct? add the button after you add the listview

Comment: I did this but I got a run Time error,

       `Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);`
       `ListView lv= this.getListView();`
       `lv.addFooterView(b);`

Comment: you can't add the footer view after the adapter has been set. you have to remove the adapter, set the footer, then set the adapter. ListView is really lame like that.

Comment: or just set the footer before you set the adapter.

Comment: here's my code, but it still gives me run time error,

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     
     
   Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   ListView lv= this.getListView();
   lv.addFooterView(b);
   
     
   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, R.layout.main, month));
   
    

 }`

Comment: if i remeber correctly, you have to do `setListAdapter(null); lv.addFooterView(b); setListAdapter(listadapter);`

Comment: if that doesn't work you'll have to either post the exception, or ask another question